# After binding gridview with crystal report...i am getting error report has no tables

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to pass gridview data to blank crystal report.but i am getting 
error "report has no tables"
i have used a button on which crystal report is to be viewed.
kindly help me
i have attached the code below:-

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new 
        SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["constr"].ToString());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetDegreeName();
            }
        }

        public void GetDegreeName()
        {
            try
            {
                objlog.Action = "SelectDegree";
                objlog.StrName = "Sp_records";
                dt = SchoolMarksheet_DataLayer.GetData(objlog);
                drpdegreelist.DataSource = dt;
                drpdegreelist.Items.Clear();
                drpdegreelist.DataTextField = "Degree_Name";
                drpdegreelist.DataBind();
                drpdegreelist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select Degree--- 
                ", "0"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public void bscitclasswise()
        {
            try
            {
                objlog.Action = "DisplayRecords";
                objlog.StrName = "Sp_records";
                objlog.Degree_Id = drpdegreelist.SelectedIndex;
                dt = SchoolMarksheet_DataLayer.GetData(objlog);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    Gridview.DataSource = dt;
                    Gridview.DataBind();

                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btnprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // for viewing crystal report on button click
            try
            {
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rd = new 
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                rd.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rpt");
                rd.SetDataSource(dt);

                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource= rd;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }      
    }
}
```

And how can i print this crystal report on paper?